# Issues with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using a `Navigation Drawer` but having problems running the Navigation Drawer. I have used toast but I am having issues as `toast` is not showing up and clicking on item not calling the next `activity`.

```
    package com.taaam.activities;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
    import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
    import com.taaam.R;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity /*implements 
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener */{

    androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar toolbar;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.tb_activity_main);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.activity_navigation_drawer);

        //For Back Key in toolbar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //For implementing the back key if(id==R.id.home){ finish();}
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nv_navigation_view);
       /* navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);*/

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, 
        R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);

        toggle.syncState();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {

            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
        }

        /*navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {*/

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected (MenuItem menuItem){

        int id = menuItem.getItemId();
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

        if (id == R.id.item_order) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Orders", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Orders.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.item_notifications) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Notifications", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Notifications.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.item_help) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Help", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Help.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.item_settings) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Settings.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.item_faqs) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FAQ's", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Faqs.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.item_contact_us) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Contact Us", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContactUs.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.item_logout) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logout", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Logout.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        /*switch (id) {

            case R.id.item_order:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Orders",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Orders.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.item_notifications:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Notifications",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            case R.id.item_help:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Help",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            case R.id.item_settings:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Settings",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            case R.id.item_faqs:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"FAQ's",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            case R.id.item_contact_us:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Contact Us",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            case R.id.item_logout:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Logout",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;*/
        }
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        return true;
    }
    });
    }
    }
```

Below is the `xml` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_navigation_drawer"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/nv_navigation_view"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/activity_navigation_header"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_navigation_menu"
    android:background="@color/colorGrey"/>
<include
    layout="@layout/activity_main"/>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>**
```

Comment: Please include the `xml` file wherein the mentioned navigation drawer.

Comment: I have just added the file you asked.

Comment: Only one think. What's about trying to use "runOnUIThread()" eg: `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Log.d("UI thread", "I am the UI thread");
    }
});`

Comment: You need to call this method `setupDrawerContent` from the `onCreate`

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView)` method from the `onCreate` and use the below code as reference.

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);

            toolbar = findViewById(R.id.tb_activity_main);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.activity_navigation_drawer);

            //For Back Key in toolbar
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            //For implementing the back key if(id==R.id.home){ finish();}
            navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nv_navigation_view);
            navigationView.bringToFront();
            /* navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);*/
            setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar,
                    R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer);
            drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);

            toggle.syncState();
        }
```

Comment: I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: Please check the updated answer and include `navigationView.bringToFront();` after this `navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nv_navigation_view);`

Comment: it crashes the app.